# How to compare uploaded server  file version with the app version which is on android market

Tags: android, android-intent

i am trying to check for and update after 24 hours for an android application whenever a user start up my application, i have written this code , but it is not working , it is not showing any message for an update available.

i have uploaded a txt file on the sever where i have just wrote 3 as a version number, i named this file version and the path to this file is  www.mywebsite.com/upload. version.txt file is present inside the upload directory.
i am not getting any dialogue message for an update available in the emulator when i run this application. please help me out finding the problem . i am new to android development.
thank in advance.

```
package com.test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import android.net.Uri;



public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler mHandler;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mHandler = new Handler();

        SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
        long lastUpdateTime = prefs.getLong("lastUpdateTime", 0);

        /* Should Activity Check for Updates Now? */
        if ((lastUpdateTime + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) < System.currentTimeMillis()) {

            /* Save current timestamp for next Check*/
            lastUpdateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();            
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
            editor.putLong("lastUpdateTime", lastUpdateTime);
            editor.commit();        

            Thread checkUpdate = null;
            /* Start Update */            
            checkUpdate.start();

            /* This Thread checks for Updates in the Background */
            Thread checkUpdatee = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        URL updateURL = new URL("http://mywebsite.com/update");                
                        URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection(); 
                        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

                        int current = 0;
                        while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
                             baf.append((byte)current);
                        }

                        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
                        final String s = new String(baf.toByteArray());         

                        /* Get current Version Number */
                        int curVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.test", 0).versionCode;
                        int newVersion = Integer.valueOf(s);

                        /* Is a higher version than the current already out? */
                        if (newVersion > curVersion) {
                            Runnable showUpdate = null;
                            /* Post a Handler for the UI to pick up and open the Dialog */
                            mHandler.post(showUpdate);
                        }                
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            };

            /* This Runnable creates a Dialog and asks the user to open the Market */ 
            Runnable showUpdate = new Runnable(){
                   public void run(){
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(TestActivity.this)

                    .setTitle("Update Available")
                    .setMessage("An update for is available!\\n\\nOpen Android Market and see the details?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    /* User clicked OK so do some stuff */
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:com.test"));
                                    startActivity(intent);
                            }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    /* User clicked Cancel */
                            }
                    })
                    .show();
                   }
            };    


        }




    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to Log the downloaded version number? e.g. `Log.d(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), newVersion)` to check if your download is working?

Comment: thank for a quick reply, i really dont know where should i place this code and how it will work , can you please place this code inside the above code..thanks

Comment: That means that you don't have any idea what the code above actually does, I assume. I would recommend to understand it first by splitting it in parts and finding out what each part does. You should read most of the developer guide http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html and also try looking inside http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html to find out what each method in the code does.